# Python new line is sort list issue

Tags: python, sorting, replace, lambda, truncate

Currently I am trying to figure some things out with the sort system as you will say with my other questions. You can find some info there if you need too.

My issue here is that I want a neatly ordered sort system which I seem to have broken.

I have a txt file that has the following data in:
Alex 8
John 4
Reece 7
Alex 8
Rebecca 2

** NEW SORTING METHOD STILL DOES NOT WORK **

```
def sortNumeric(fileName, i, toWrite):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as inFile:
        pairs = sorted((l.strip().split() for l in inFile),
                   key=operator.itemgetter(1))

with open(fileName, 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(os.linesep.join(p[0] + ' ' + p[1] for p in pairs))
```

It currently writes this to file:

Reece0John

Not even including John's score or anything!
I need it written to file like so:

Rebecca 2
John 3
Reece 7
Alex 8
Alex 8

So going downwards rather than being on one line. Any help or improvements to my sort system would be greatly appreciated.

Just in case the rest of my program is messing this up... here is the whole thing!

[code](http://pastebin.com/wJutHmf2)

Comment: change to `f.write(str(pairs)+"\n")`

Comment: Done. Still have the same issue with it writing on a single line

Comment: dont open it with notepad ... open it with notepad++ or wordpad ... or prettymuch anything but notepad ... or change it to `f.write(str(pairs)+"\r\n")`

Comment: The same thing again aha. Opened in multiple text editors!

Comment: your right i didnt look at your code close enough

Comment: I added the full code. I don't know if anything else is causing it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what all that replacing (and truncating) is for..

```
import os

def mykey(item):
    int(item[1])

def sortNumeric(fileName, i, toWrite):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as inFile:
        pairs = sorted((l.strip().split() for l in inFile),
                       key=mykey)

    with open(toWrite, 'w') as outFile:
        outfile.write(os.linesep.join(p[0] + ' ' + p[1] for p in pairs))
```

As a short (non-file) example..

```
>>> infile = ['Alex 8', 'John 4', 'Reece 7', 'Alex 8', 'Rebbecca 2']
>>> pairs = sorted((l.strip().split() for l in infile),
...                    key=mykey)
>>> os.linesep.join(p[0] + ' ' + p[1] for p in pairs)
'Rebbecca 2\nJohn 4\nReece 7\nAlex 8\nAlex 8'
>>> print(os.linesep.join(p[0] + ' ' + p[1] for p in pairs))
Rebbecca 2
John 4
Reece 7
Alex 8
Alex 8
>>>
```

Comment: The replacing is because I have all these "[[ , '' ]]" characters in my list. Like I don't need them.

Comment: Also I am writing to file so I need to clear previous unsorted data from it

Comment: Opening a file with 'w' will truncate, you don't have to do it manually

Comment: What about all the "[[Reece, [0], [..." etc characters that are not needed

Comment: If the input file looks the way you said it does, those characters aren't there..

Comment: Yes because I used .replace to get rid of them all!

Comment: They were never there to begin with. You added them by turning your list of lists into a string, rather than creating a list of strings.

Comment: Ok I tried your method and now the output file is this:  
**Reece 0John**

Not creating a new line and not giving the next user a score?

Comment: then either your input file isn't what you said it is, or you've done something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
"\n".join(name_score[0] + " " + name_score[1] for name_score in pairs)
```

as the result of the *join* is not assigned to anything.

You should prefix that line with `pairs =`:

```
pairs = "\n".join(name_score[0] + " " + name_score[1] for name_score in pairs)
```

Comment: Thats what is assigned too. Either way it does the same thing

Comment: `... for name_score in pairs` is [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), it does not update *pairs*, so you do need the assignment. If it still does not work, then there is another issue, but you need this change at least.

Comment: That is not really what you should have done, now my answer makes no sense any more. Please restore the previous version, and add the new code at the end.

Answer (score 0):

just let the whole `str()` thing be, you don't need it:

```
def sortNumeric(fileName, toWrite):
    pairs = [l.strip().split(" ") for l in open(fileName, "r")]
    pairs.sort(key = lambda name_score: int(name_score[1]))
    f = open(toWrite, "w")
    f.write("\n".join(name_score[0] + " " + name_score[1] for name_score in pairs))
    f.close()
```

Comment: I took your code right there and it threw this error: **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1John'**. It saved the first score then when I ran the program for the second try it threw that

Comment: I think your input file is corrupt because you don't use the `toWrite`  parameter in your method and overwrite the input file (you dont use `i` neighter). Once wrong, always wrong:)